# Where to add Custom Cloud Container id in Xcode (Not using developer account)

Tags: ios, swift, containers, icloud, cloudkit

I am new to the IOS development. I got a Bundle id,p12 certificate,provisional profile and a container ID from my admin who is the owner of the developer account. I am trying to build an app where I need to sync iCloud and hence using cloud kit. So from my Apple ID (free) I managed to enable cloud kit in my capabilities but somehow I cannot select Custom container or default container. I know I have to mention my "Custom container ID" somewhere but I am clueless as I don't see any relative field to mention the same. 
PS : I can unable the CloudKit but as soon as I click on the cloudKit under service section, a pop up appears saying "Add a new account to the account preference pan or verify that your accounts has valid credentials" 
I repeat I don't have a developer id, P12 and provisional certificate along with container id was provided to me by Higher authorities. 
Thanks in Advance, Ankit.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer to my own question. One cannot add Container id anywhere. It is mandatory to log in using the developer account, irrespective of one integrating p12 and provisioning profile only.
Thanks.